# Use interior color in cells to choose e-mail addresses to store in a string

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

In range A10 till A14 there are names. These names all have a specific e-mail address like in my code below. A10 = a, A11 = b, A12 = c and so on. Names and e-mail addresses are fakes of course.

I want to loop through the cells A10 till A14 and if the interior color of the cells are code 43 then store the e-mail address in the variable "namen". So if I click A10 and A12 string a and c should be in "namen".

Now it only shows string a in my e-mail recipients.

```
Sub mailen()
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim namen As String
Dim inhoud As String

a = "brrr@hotmail.com;"
b = "grrr@hotmail.com;"
c = "crrr@hotmail.com.com;"

If Range("A10").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
    namen = a
ElseIf Range("A10").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 And Range("A11").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
    namen = a & b
Else: MsgBox "Geen namen geselecteerd"
End If

With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
    inhoud = "Hoi Vincent"
    .to = namen
    .Subject = "Test"
    .body = inhoud
    .attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .display
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a For-Each loop through each cell of your range, check the colour, if 43 concatenate to your output string.

Comment: @SJR 
I thougth of this so far but how do I store this?

```
With Sheet("Blad4")
For Each cell In Range("A10:A14")
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub mailen()

Dim namen As String
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("A10:A14")
    If r.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
        namen = namen & r
    End If
Next r

msgbox namen

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
here is an example of code for your project 
Pre requisite :

1. create a sheet with the name mailingList
2. add your list of email with colored or not colored property

   ```
   Dim n As Integer
   Dim myMailingList As String
   Dim currentMail As String
   myMailingList = ""
   currentMail = ""

   n = 1

   Do While Not (IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("mailingList").Cells(n, 1)))

       currentMail = ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("mailingList").Cells(n, 1).Value
       Debug.Print (" color index of the current cell : " & ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("mailingList").Cells(n, 1).Interior.ColorIndex)
       If ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("mailingList").Cells(n, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
           myMailingList = currentMail & ";" & myMailingList
       End If

   ' next row
   n = n + 1
   Loop
   ```

Comment: This also works very good, but the other solution is easier for me to read :P
But thank you too for your efford on this one!! Saved it for research purposes.